# WCF service authentication using System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService, I can't authenticate to the membership provider

Tags: asp.net, wcf, authentication, forms-authentication, membership-provider

I'm trying to get authenticated using the the Authentication Service and my Membership Provider. Ideally I want to call my membership provider, but I bomb out before hitting my provider. Says a token cannot be validated. Checking my error log, it appears I'm trying to Authenticate using Windows auth. That's not what I'm intending to do.  This is a web with an svc file. I use svcUtil and generate a client from the WSDL. I have a test page in the app that I'm using the client from. Its just a test page and will not be deployed. I see Integrated Windows Auth is checked in IIS which doesnt seem correct, but if I uncheck it, Visual Studio won't debug.  Anyways I look in the event log and get two errors

```
Logon Failure:
 Reason:        Unknown user name or bad password
 User Name:    sandagtestuser
 Domain:        
 Logon Type:    8
 Logon Process:    Advapi  
 Authentication Package:    MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
 Workstation Name:    SDD-CK

Logon attempt by: MICROSOFT_AUTHENTICATION_PACKAGE_V1_0
Logon account:  sandagtestuser
Source Workstation: SDD-CK
Error Code: 0xC0000064
```

Here are the bindings in the web.config. Please note I'm trying to use SSL and HTTPS. This is my first stab at WCF security

```
<system.serviceModel>
        <client>
        <endpoint address="https://SDD-CK/ATISServices/Services/AuthService.svc/AuthService"
              binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="userHttps_AuthenticationService"
              contract="AuthenticationService" name="userHttps_AuthenticationService" >
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
    <behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
              <behavior name="ATISServices.AuthServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>

            <binding name="userHttps_AuthenticationService" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
               openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
               allowCookies="true" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
               maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
               messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
               useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport proxyCredentialType="None" clientCredentialType="None" realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />                       
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="basic_auth_config">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>

    </bindings>
    <services>

        <service behaviorConfiguration="ATISServices.AuthServiceBehavior"
            name="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService">

            <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingName="userHttps" bindingConfiguration="basic_auth_config"
                bindingNamespace="http://asp.net/ApplicationServices/v200"
                contract="System.Web.ApplicationServices.AuthenticationService"
                address="AuthService"/>

            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
                contract="IMetadataExchange" />  

        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Perhaps some WCF guru out there can help me correct the problem. I see the credentials getting up to the server via the event log, so I must not be too terribly far off.  The actual InnerException message on the fault is `At least one security token in the message could not be validated.`

Lastly here are some additional web.config settings that may be of interest.

```
 <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
        <webServices>
            <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL="true"/>
        </webServices>

    </scripting>
</system.web.extensions>

 <authentication mode="Forms" >
        <forms cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>

 <membership defaultProvider="KCMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add
            name="KCMembershipProvider"
            applicationName="/"
            type="zcore.MembershipProvider.KCMembershipProvider, zcore.MembershipProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null"  />
        </providers>
    </membership>
```

Any help or tips at this point would be greatly appreciated. I've battled with this for two days. I'm using certificates as well. I made them with 'makecert' tool. One is a Cert Authority and the other is a 'localhost' cert using said Authority. I also have used httpcfg and set the cert thumbprint to port 9307, however when i put ":9307" on the service address, I get connection actively refused. I truly appreciate any help here.

Cheers,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This actually got it to work. Adding this to the service behavior.

```
 <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider" membershipProviderName="KCMembershipProvider"/>
      </serviceCredentials>
```